# Changing Log Levels in Laravel 4

Tags: php, logging, laravel, laravel-4, error-logging

The laravel documentation indicates on the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/errors) that `"The logger provides the seven logging levels defined in RFC 5424: debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, and alert."`, but where should this be changed is something that is not provided. Could someone help me understand how this works and where the log level needs to be changed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Figured it out by looking at the [LogWriter](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php#L80-L85) Class. Not sure if this is the right approach but, there should be a config on the Laravel App that should set the Laravel Logging Level.

This is what currently needs to be done to change the logging level.

Go to `app/start/global.php` (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/start/global.php#L36) and on `Line 36`, you would find the code

```
Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$logFile);
```

This needs to be changed to

```
Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path() . '/logs/' . $logFile, 0, 'error');
```

The third parameter is where the log level needs to be changed and the following are the log levels that can be used

- debug
- info
- notice
- warning
- error
- critical
- alert

Hope this helps who ever have been searching for this. I hope there is a simpler way to do this instead of changing the function parameter.

Comment: Just a quick note for users of Laravel 4.1. You'll find `Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log');' instead. This can safely be updated to what is shown above for daily logging or `Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log', 'error');` to stay with a single log file.

Comment: What is the second parameter? (0)

Comment: @Inigo according to the source code, it's the `$days` value. Which is the amount of day files to keep. `0` = unlimited.

Answer (score 23):

We can take Abishek's answer one step further. If we add the log levels to our config files, we can change the log level based on the environment we're in. In config/app.php:

```
'log_level' => 'debug',
```

and in config/prod/app.php:

```
'log_level' => 'warning',
```

We then change the daily logger to

```
Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path() . '/logs/' . $logFile, 0, Config::get('app.log_level'));
```

and we have configurable logging.